# Angular app-level service not instantiating in lazy-loaded route

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

When the SPA intially loads (through the main app component), an authentication service is instantiated successfully.

However, when a user enters the SPA directly through a lazy-loaded route (not through the login screen), the authentication service is not being instantiated.

Tried:

- Using the `providedIn: 'root'` property on the `@Injectable()` decorator for the service.
- Fully declaring the provider in the `CoreModule` with `{provide: AuthService, useClass: AuthService}`
- Fully declaring the provider in the `CoreModule` with `{provide: AuthService, useExisting: AuthService}`
- Also declaring the service in the lazy-loaded module

**app.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    // other components
],

  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    // other modules
  ],

  exports: [],

  providers: [
    // some providers
],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**core.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
      // some modules
    ],

    exports: [],

    providers: [
      AuthService,
      // other providers
    ],
})
```

**app-routing.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**routes.ts**:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { 
      path: '', 
      component: LoginComponent, 
      resolve: [StaticDataGuard]
    },
    {
      path: 'entry',
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      resolve: [StaticDataGuard],
      loadChildren: () => import('../entry/entry.module').then(m => m.EntryModule)
    },
    // other paths
];
```

**entry.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [EntryComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    // other components
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(entryRoutes),
    // other modules
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [
    // some providers (not AuthService, though...)
],
})
```

**entry.routes.ts**:

```
export const entryRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: EntryComponent }
]
```

**auth.service.ts**:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor() {
        console.log("I'm here!");
    }
}
```

I expect that any provider declared in the root injector would be available even if the entry to the SPA was through a lazy-loaded route.

However the `console.log()` is never triggered unless the user accesses the SPA through the initially bootstrapped `AppComponent` and then navigates to the lazy-loaded route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.

It seems as though Angular Services don't *"live on their own"*, even if they're part of the current module's `providers`. Unless injected into a `Component` (or `Directive`, probably), they will **not** be constructed.

I ended up injecting it like so, and everything worked fine:

```
constructor(
  private auth: AuthService,
  // other injections
) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't leave comment so answering here, did you generate the service through cli, because that would automatically add it to the providers array in app.module.ts, if you put it there, and remove import from every other place you should be able to get it.

Comment: The service wasn't created through the CLI, and the only place where it has been declared is the ' CoreModule` (which is imported solely in the `AppModule`). 
I tried declaring the `AuthService` directly in the `AppModule`, to no avail...